# Choppy Animation SwiftUI Nested Views

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I'm working on an animation that brings up a view from the bottom of the screen above part of the view that previously occupied the screen. My code is technically working, though I'm concerned that the animation looks too choppy. Basically, what I think is happening is that the new, rising view is composed of several other views, and when I animate it coming up, it also animates the sub-views coming together--something I don't like the look of.

Sample Code:

```
struct ButtonView: View {
    @State var show: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack {
                Button(action: { withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.5)) { show = !show }} )  {
                    Text("Press Me")
                }
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }
        if show {
            VStack {
                CollapsibleView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CollapsibleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Text 1")
                Text("Text 2")
                Text("Text 3")
            }
            .background(Color.white)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the duration is set to be quite long for illustration purposes, but even at smaller duration values I can still notice the choppy effect.

How do I avoid this? Is there a way to just animate the motion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a way for what you may looking for:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var show: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button(action: { show.toggle() }, label: { show ? Text("hide") : Text("show") })
                .animation(nil)
            
            Color.gray
            
            Group {
                
                if show { CollapsibleView().transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .bottom), removal: .move(edge: .bottom))) }
                
            }
            .opacity(show ? 1.0 : 0.0)
            
        }
        .animation(Animation.spring(response: 0.4, dampingFraction: 0.4, blendDuration: 1.0), value: show)
        
        
    }
}

struct CollapsibleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Text 1")
            Text("Text 2")
            Text("Text 3")
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really interested in the spring effect, but it does seem like you fixed the choppy issue by including all the text elements in a single VStack. Is it possible to have the non-choppy effect with nested views?

Comment: Or maybe I mis-interpreted what your code is doing... I just ran it with sub-views in the CollapsibleView and it worked just fine.

Comment: VStack is your own code! Not me!

Comment: Ok that makes more sense

Comment: With the `.transition` thing you added--how do you make it transparent? Now I want to have a new view slide up with a certain color covering the entire space and there is a white area around it from the transition-thing bringing it up. I can post a code example if that would helpful.